# Angular2 with ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, angular

There are many tutorials across all the internet about using VS2015 MVC5 and Angular2, but none about VS2013 MVC4 Angular2. The project structure is differs from the one described in MVC5 tutorials. Can anyone help with set up MVC4+A2 project correctlly? Maybe someone can provide any tutorial links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic setups using your config:

From there on you should be able to follow other NG2 tutorials, good luck!

[Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition with .NET 4.5 Angular 2 setup](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1060262/First-Angular-App-with-TypeScript-and-Visual-Studi)

[Visual Studio 2013 with Angular 2](http://codeinreview.com/205/vs2013-typescript-and-angular-2/)